# Widget causes app to hit onCreate

Tags: android

I have a home screen widget with a button, that when clicked on, starts my main activity.

Every time I click on the widget, my main activity launches and runs through onCreate.

However, if I open my app from the app drawer, it doesn't run through onCreate every time. Only the first time after I install it. But the widget does it every time.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you're trying to get some logic to run every time the app comes to the foreground, you may want to consider performing this action in a different Activity lifecycle method, like onResume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is :-)

Add the attribute

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to the activity you don't want to call onCreate everytime. [LaunchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

**or**

add the flag to your startActivity(Intent):

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

This will make the Activity start in the method [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) and not go through onCreate

:-)